# Executing a PHP Script From A Bash Script

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute a simple PHP script from a simple BASH script. The answers on this website don't answer my issue.

Here is my BASH script

```
#!/bin/sh
railmove="/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/subfolder"
php "$railmove"/$shelltest.php
```

Here is my PHP script

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<html>
<head>
</head><body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);             
require('connect_db.php');           
$timer="222222";               
$railinfo2=$mysql_link->prepare('INSERT INTO stillrunning(timer) VALUES(:timer)');
$railinfo2->execute(array(':timer'=>$timer));                          
$mysql_link=null;
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error when I run my BASH script from the command line.

```
Could not open input file: /usr/bin/php -q /home/username/subfolder/.php
```

I have tried typing /usr/bin/php -q /home/username/subfolder/durable2.sh and that works fine. ie it runs

Comment: so where's `$shelltest` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already include `/usr/bin/php` in the `$railmove` string.  You don't need to specify `php` again as a new command.  Also, `$shelltest` doesn't appear to be defined.

So:

```
#!/bin/sh
railmove="/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/subfolder"
$railmove/your-php-script.php
```

might work.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. The $ in front of the shelltest was part of the problem and adding your script change also helped